# Is this correct way to play video after download the video from server or not

Tags: android

Which of the following is better way to play video in Android:

1. Stream the Video Url from server and play.
2. or after download the video from the server and play video.

Thanks in Advance........

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 works better if the device is connected to a internet connection that can handle the strain. Since everyone hates buffering!
Option 2 is better otherwise.

But it also depends on the size of the video and other variables, such as how many times the user will watch the clip, when the user wants to see it (the second he starts your app or one/two minutes later) and such!

Answer (score 0):

There's no common answer to your question

Streaming is better when

1) Internet connection is fast enough to stream without buffering

2) User needs to watch video immediately, without waiting for downloading

3) User will watch video only one-two times

Downloading is better when

1) User wants to watch video later, not right after downloading

2) User will watch video several times, so streaming will lead to excess traffic